# Pairwise intersections of segments in a rectangle

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, computational-geometry, search-algorithms

Let V be a set of vertical segments, and H be a set of segments parallel to a line (e.g. a line with slope -1). We want to find a data structure for set S = V ∪ H to find all pairs (v,h) of segments intersecting in an axis-parallel query rectangle, where v∊V and h∊H.

For orthogonal input segments (i.e. segments parallel to either axis), an optimal time solution exists [1](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-19094-0_14), but I do not know whether a non-trivial solution exists for the above problem. I will be grateful if someone could provide any suggestion(s) regarding it.

Comment: Maybe you could apply a shear transformation so that the segments are axis-aligned, after which the query rectangle becomes a query parallelogram. A parallelogram is made up of two triangles, so if you can solve the problem with axis-aligned segments and a query triangle, you can solve the problem posed. Of course you can also approximate a query triangle with a bunch of rectangles, so in practice that might be a good approach.